# Can you disable AVX in deepfacelab?

Tags: python, cpu, cpu-architecture, avx, deep-fake

A few month ago I discovered "Deepfacelab", a software with which you can create deepfakes. It is an folder-structure, so open source I guess.

Recently I tried switching from my home pc to a server which can hold multiple graphics-cards to speed up the training process. The problem was that the training process did not start (at least SAEHD and AMP didn't, Quick 96 worked for some reason). So we tried many, many things, updated the Gpu dirvers, tried different builds of DFL, installed several extensions, like python, numpy and so on..

We came to the conclusion that the Cpu in my home Pc has AVX and the one in the server has not, which apparently is a requirement for Deepfacelab.

Since replacing the old Cpu with a new one is not an option at this moment, I wondered wether you can prevent DFL from wanting to use AVX? I mean, there has to be somewhere in the program the declaration to use AVX right?

I tried finding the file where this is being declared but sadly I am not skilled enough to orientate myself in this jungle of code :/
My question is: Is anyone here experienced enough to tell me first: If it is possible at all, and secondly: Where one could turn this reliance to AVX off?

If you're in and want to take a look, here is the link to the github page: https://github.com/iperov/DeepFaceLab
Under "releases" you can find the download links; I used the Mega.nz link for Windows and chose the following build: DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti_build_11_20_2021.exe

Also If you need any additional information, just comment down below :)

My Father and I would very much appreciate any replies to this.

Regards,
Armin

Answer (score 0):

AVX is a (TF) tensorflow thing. You should get a version of TF with no AVX. Some people publish TF compilations with no AVX enabled for older CPUs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).